# Does the use of set containers in c++ classes require memory release?

Tags: c++, stl

```
class rfdevice_ams2_l9s_cn_qm13341_sub_MIPI_data_ag:public rfdevice_asm2_data
{
public:
  static rfdevice_asm2_data * get_instance();
  ***std::set<int> Band_Count;***
  bool THCH_NRCA = false;
  bool THCH_ENDC = false;
  bool THCH_LTE_LTECA = false;
  bool THCH_GSM = false;
  bool THCH_WCDMA = false;
  bool THCH_CDMA = false;
  int Band_res;
  void Count_Band(rfdevice_asm2_tuning_data_info *tuning_data, int ant_cur,  uint8 scenario);
  void port_cc();
  boolean Get_NR_NRCA(rfdevice_asm2_tuning_data_info *tuning_data, uint8 *port, uint8 scenario);
  boolean Get_LTE_SIGNLE(rfdevice_asm2_tuning_data_info *tuning_data, uint8 *port, uint8 scenario);
  void TECH_Judge(rfdevice_asm2_tuning_data_info *tuning_data, uint8 scenario);
  boolean port_cc(rfdevice_asm2_tuning_data_info *tuning_data, uint8 *port, uint8 scenario);
  boolean get_script(rfdevice_asm2_cfg_params_type *cfg, rfdevice_asm2_settings_type_u *settings);

 ~rfdevice_ams2_l9s_cn_qm13341_sub_MIPI_data_ag(void);  /*  Destructor  */

protected:
  rfdevice_ams2_l9s_cn_qm13341_sub_MIPI_data_ag(void);  /*  Constructor  */

private:
  static rfdevice_asm2_data *rfdevice_ams2_l9s_cn_qm13341_sub_data_ptr;
};
```

Does the use of set containers in c++ classes need to release memory?
For example, std::set Band_Count in here;Do I need to release memory in the destructor?

Comment: If an instance of `rfdevice_ams2_l9s_cn_qm13341_sub_MIPI_data_ag` is destroyed, so too goes it's `Band_Count`.

Comment: `void rfdevice_ams2_l9s_glb_qm13341_sub_MIPI_data_ag::CC_Judge(rfdevice_asm2_tuning_data_info *tuning_data, int Ant_sum, uint8 scenario)
{
  Band_Count.clear();
  for(int Ant_Cur = 0; Ant_Cur != Ant_sum; ++Ant_Cur)
  {
    rfdevice_ams2_l9s_glb_qm13341_sub_MIPI_data_ag::Count_Band(tuning_data,Ant_Cur, scenario);
  }
  Band_res = Band_Count.size();
  Band_Count.clear();

}`I cleared the band_count container twice in cc_judge, will it cause the error of free the memory block twice?

Comment: Please edit and add a [mre] to show what problems you are facing.

Comment: `(void)` is a pattern inherited from C, which for historical reasons needed a special syntax to denote the empty argument list. C++ doesn't need it. It's especially weird to see on destructors, since C doesn't have destructors and in C++ destructors can't take arguments anyway.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has destructors, which *should* clear all memory. For the (template) classes in the C++ library, that's always the case.

Calling `set::clear()` before the destructor runs is a way to remove all objects from the set, releasing the memory used for the contained objects. `set::size()` will be zero afterwards. That does mean there is a very, *very* small amount of memory still needed, to record the fact that there are zero elements. This small amount of bookkeeping is `sizeof(std::set<int>)`.

`std::set<YourClass>::clear()` will call the destructors of `YourClass`, so that memory too is reclaimed. But `int` has no destructors (it's not a class) so `std::set<int>::clear()` is a bit simpler.

Comment: The clear function should just clear the elements inside, but it will not release the memory. Will it cause a problem if I use the clear function before the destructor

Comment: @郑Toby: I'm not sure what you mean by "**the** memory. Each element takes a bit of memory. `.clear()` removes all elements, and all the memory use by all the elements.